# Simulating Touch Event in Windows 8

Tags: c#, camera, touch, gesture, simulate

I'm creating an application (C#) using finger tracking via camera, and need to simulate a touch even where the user's finger is located.

How do I simulate a touch event within Windows 8?
This is a Windows 8 only application, so don't worry about compatibility.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows have [InjectTouchInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802881(v=vs.85).aspx) function for simulating touch input. There is .NET-wrapper for it in [TCD.System.TouchInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TCD.System.TouchInjection/) NuGet package. Also you can try to pInvoke it by yourself - it's not very complicated.

Comment: Thank you I was unaware of this and will give it a try!

Comment: rufanov, do you know how to simulate the drag effect of the touch input? I'm initiating my touches via a loop, and would like for it to also simulate the drag effect. Thank you!